# UDP packages appear in wireshark, but are not received by program

Tags: python, udp, wireshark

I am trying to read UDP packages sent by an FPGA with my computer. They are sent
to port 21844 and to the IP 192.168.1.2 (which is my computer's IP). I can see the package in wireshark, they have no errors. When I run however this little python script, then only a very very small fraction of all packages are received by it, also depending if wireshark is running or not.

```
import socket
import sys


HOST, PORT = "192.168.1.2", 21844
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((HOST,PORT)) 
received ,address= sock.recvfrom(2048)
print address
```

I use windows 7 with Norton Internet Security, where I allow all traffic in the firewall for the FPGA IP and also for python. The same program on a Windows XP computer does not receive anything either...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you say that the "XP computer does not receive anything either", do you really mean a very small fraction of the packets, as per the Windows 7 machine? Also, how fast are packets being delivered?

Comment: No, the XP computer does not get anything at all..
The packets from the FPGA arrive with a frequency of around one per second, and have a data length of 1196Bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem: The UDP checksum in the FPGA was computed wrongly. Wireshark shows every package, but by default it does not check if the checksum is correct. When I set the checksum to `0x0000`, then the packages arrive in python! Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 3):

The TCP/IP stack of your OS doesn't hold those packets for you for eternity. Your script looks like something that very much depends on *when* it is run. Try to `recvfrom` in a loop, and run the script in the background. Then, start sending packets from your FPGA.

For extra convenience, explore the `SocketServer` module from Python's stdlib.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eli! I actually also tried to use it in a loop, like: 

while 1:
   received ,address= sock.recvfrom(2048)
   print received, address

Also in this case only a very small amount of the packages was captured...