# recv Python does not receive

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ethernet

I'm new to Python and Ethernet and I'm trying to send and receive UDP frames from my computer to an Ethernet device that should answer to specific commands.

This what I use to perform this task (simplified version) :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.5', 1911))
s.settimeout(1)
s.sendall(b'Hello world')

while True:
  try:
    r_data = s.recv(2048)
    print('Received', repr(r_data))
  except socket.timeout:
    print("timeout socket")
    break
```

I monitored the link with wireshark, commands and answers are well present but my code returns `socket.timeout: timed out`

Did I miss something ?

Comment: To LISTEN on a UDP port, you have to use `bind`.  `connect`, which is optional, just specifies the default address for a `send` if you don't give one.  HOWEVER, you need to bind to an address on your local computer.  UDP doesn't have "connections", so you can't "listen for traffic from 192.168.0.5".  You have to listen for all incoming traffic on that port.  Like, `s.bind(('0.0.0.0',1911)`, assuming the device sends data back on the same port it listens on.

Comment: @TimRoberts that sounds a bit confused.  `bind` only ensures that the socket will be bound to a specific address, otherwise "the  socket  layer  will  automatically  assign  a  free  local  port".  OP might want to `print(s.getsockname())` to see what local address was automatically assigned

Comment: could some firewall software be getting in the way and discarding the packet between what wireshark sees and your code does?

Comment: Knowing the local address doesn't help here.  The key is that the other end already has some standard to decide where it will send its response, and his code has to bind to that address.  It's often the same port number it received on.

Comment: @TimRoberts most server code I've seen sends responses back to the packet's source address (which would include the port number).  hence OP's code would do the right thing.  e.g. if you do a DNS query you don't bind to port 53, just the server does that.  would be good for OP to confirm that the packet is coming back to the address that `getsockname` returns.

Comment: @SamMason Wireshark indicates that first UDP comand is going from 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.5 port 62845(not fixed) to 1911 then answer is 192.168.0.5 to 192.168.0.10 port 1911 to 62845.

Comment: @boby that sounds good, not sure why it's not working then.  my other guess was that you've got some firewall software that's causing the packet to disappear before it's delivered to python

Comment: This resolved my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928507/udp-packages-appear-in-wireshark-but-are-not-received-by-program